# gnucash crashes on trying to enter text in transaction description field

Tags: xubuntu, gnucash

I've used gnucash successfully until some years ago and would like to start using it again. I installed it from the standard Ubuntu packets. Now what works is: Modify account tree, including renaming accounts and adding new ones. What doesn't: Enter a transaction. I can place the cursor in an entry field for a transaction, but as soon as I only press the Shift Key or any letter key to enter anything in that field, gnucash crashes without any trace that I can see. Started from a terminal, it leaves the message:

```
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

in English:

```
Memory access error (memory dumped)
```

My system is this:

Xubuntu 19.04
Intel Core i5-7400 CPU @ 3 GHz 8 GB RAM
Graphics 3840 x 2160 Pixel
MESA DRI Intel HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)
The X.Org Foundation

*Gnucash*
Version: 3.4
Build ID: 3.4+ (2018-12-30)
Finance::Quote: 1.47

On two older laptop computers in our household, under the same OS, gnucash works as expected.

What can I do to narrow down where things go wrong?

Here are free -h and sudo lshw -C memory:

```
thomas@Schleiereule:~$ free -h
          Gesamt   belegt    frei        gemns. Puffer/Cache verfügbar
Speicher:       7,7Gi       4,7Gi       1,4Gi       1,1Gi       1,5Gi       1,6Gi
Auslagerungsspeicher:        14Gi       5,5Gi       9,4Gi

thomas@Schleiereule:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       Beschreibung: BIOS
       Hersteller: American Megatrends Inc.
       Physische ID: 0
       Version: 1.70
       date: 05/08/2017
       Größe: 64KiB
       Kapazität: 15MiB
       Fähigkeiten: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       Beschreibung: Systemspeicher
       Physische ID: 3c
       Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine
       Größe: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR4 Synchron 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
          Produkt: CT8G4DFD824A.C16FBD1
          Hersteller: 859B
          Physische ID: 0
          Seriennummer: 1517B96C
          Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM0
          Größe: 8GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920) [leer]
          Physische ID: 1
          Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920) [leer]
          Physische ID: 2
          Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:3
          Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2019-04-12 08:46+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18920) [leer]
          Physische ID: 3
          Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-cache:0
       Beschreibung: L1 Cache
       Physische ID: 42
       Steckplatz: L1 Cache
       Größe: 256KiB
       Kapazität: 256KiB
       Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
       Konfiguration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       Beschreibung: L2 Cache
       Physische ID: 43
       Steckplatz: L2 Cache
       Größe: 1MiB
       Kapazität: 1MiB
       Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
       Konfiguration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       Beschreibung: L3 Cache
       Physische ID: 44
       Steckplatz: L3 Cache
       Größe: 6MiB
       Kapazität: 6MiB
       Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
       Konfiguration: level=3
  *-memory UNGEFORDERT
       Beschreibung: Memory controller
       Produkt: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 1f.2
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       Version: 31
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       Fähigkeiten: bus_master
       Konfiguration: latency=0
       Ressourcen: memory:df124000-df127fff
```

Comment: Translation: Memory access error (memory dumped). Please file a bug report for this issue.

Comment: What version GnuCash? Are you using an old existing database? What happens if you create a new clean database? What happens if you switch video cards? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: I did all that, apart from the bug report, yet. Clean database: Same thing. Video card: don't have one, sorry. I changed the resolution down to something pretty low: Same crash.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I have the same issue with GnuCash 3.7 under Ubuntu 19.10 eoan. GnuCash crashes with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" being the only text in the log (--debug --extra) when pressing any key in a new .gnucash file that doesn't contain a single transaction. I'd submit a bug report if only the GnuCash website were working.

Comment: I just discovered this line in my dmesg log: [32823.142925] gnucash[17983]: segfault at f8 ip 00007f61d8d85a96 sp 00007ffeca60bec8 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2404.8[7f61d8d62000+80000]
So this might not be a GnuCash but after all.